# VS 2017 C++ - "cannot open source file 'sqlite3.h' "

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I am starting to learn how to use Sqlite and build databases however I would like to be able to work with these databases in C++. Whenever I start I am unable to accomplish anything because Visual Studio gives me the error in the title. when I try:

```
 #include <sqlite3.h>
```

I have tried moving all of the code from sqlite's amalgamation into my project file and it still did not work. I tried using:

```
"sqlite3.h"
```

instead of

```
<sqlite3.h>
```

I also added the 'amalgamation' folder as a directory which makes the first error away but I am given a linker error on the build.

I feel as though I missed something in the setup that is not allowing me to do continue, but I have searched everything I can imagine and found no answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE: I am in a CLR project because I will need to attach a GUI to this Database and I am unable to compile the .c files from the  amalgamation. Those files seem to be the solution to my problem though, so is there any way to get around that issue of a C file not being able to be compiled in a CLR project?

Comment: @borgleader would that necissary lib be the sqlite3.dll? I have the .dll and .def files in one folder and the source code in another, which one should I link?

Comment: I was able to run 2nd snippet on [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) by downloading the amalamation zip file, copying its contents to the folder containing the vcxproj. Then I right-clicked the projet in VS -> Add -> Existing Item and added sqlite3.c/.h and sqlite3ext.h. Replaced <sqlite3.h> with "sqlite3.h" in the snippet and compiled.

Comment: I was unable to compile C file 'sqlite3.c' with the /clr option...

Answer (score 0):

The following method demonstrate how to link with sqlite3.dll.
Download and copy the following folder to your Visual C++ solution folder.
https://github.com/mcychan/DNAssist/tree/master/sqlite3
The sqlite3 folder contains both x86 and x64 version of sqlite dll and lib.
You may upgrade to latest version of sqlite.dll.
Download and copy the following files to your Visual C++ project folder, add reference for them.
[https://github.com/mcychan/DNAssist/blob/master/DNAssist/CppSQLite3.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcychan/DNAssist/master/DNAssist/CppSQLite3.cpp)
[https://github.com/mcychan/DNAssist/blob/master/DNAssist/CppSQLite3.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcychan/DNAssist/master/DNAssist/CppSQLite3.h)

The following is the sample code to query the database.

```
#include "CppSQLite3.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

CppSQLite3DB db;

bool GetDatabase(const string& dbPath)
{
    try {
        db.open(dbPath.c_str());
        return true;
    }
    catch (CppSQLite3Exception& e)
    {
        cout << _T("Cannot open database: ") << dbPath << _T("\n");
        return false;
    }
}

void IssueQuery(const string& querystring, const string& field1)
{
    try {
        CppSQLite3Query q = db.execQuery(querystring.c_str());
        while (!q.eof()) {
            CString temp2(q.fieldValue(field1.c_str()));
            TRACE(temp2 + _T("\n"));
            q.nextRow();
        }
    }
    catch (CppSQLite3Exception& e)
    {
        cout << _T("Cannot execute query: ") << querystring << _T("\n");
    }
}

void main()
{
    if(GetDatabase("C:\\test.sqlite"))
        IssueQuery("SELECT * FROM DUAL", "X");
}
```

Comment: I tried all of the above, and it would not find the sqlite3.h file (which I put in with my other cpp and h files (visual studio), until I hardcoded the path to it.  Now it's giving 10 errors, starting with Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0020 identifier "CppSQLite3DB" is undefined SQLiteConnect C:\Users\DSNoS\source\repos\SQLiteConnect\SQLiteConnect\SQLiteConnect.cpp 7

Comment: There is sqlite3.h in the https://github.com/mcychan/DNAssist/tree/master/sqlite3 Download and copy the following folder [sqlite3] to your Visual C++ solution folder [C:\Users\DSNoS\source\repos\SQLiteConnect]. Download and copy the following files [CppSQLite3.*] to your Visual C++ project folder [C:\Users\DSNoS\source\repos\SQLiteConnect\SQLiteConnect], add reference for them.